# Is there any way to use the all fetched row's data from mysql database within a single dimentional php array function

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

This is the traditional way where I can fetch all rows with datas and run a while loop to get them one by one with mysqli_fetch_array() function.

```
 $con = mysqli_connect(YOURLS_DB_HOST,YOURLS_DB_USER,YOURLS_DB_PASS);
     mysqli_select_db($con,YOURLS_DB_NAME);
                              $users=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users"));
                                    while($user=mysqli_fetch_array($users))     
                                         {  
                                             $user['email']; $user['pass'];
                                          }
```

Now the question is I have to insert all the rows with the respective datas into the bellow array. How is this possible. Rows will inserted one by one probably like the single line commented line. And non commented are actual data what I want.

```
$user_password = array(

    'username2' => 'password2',  
    /* You can have one or more*/ 'login'=>'password',

              // $user['email']  => $user['pass'],                  


    )
```

I have done something and current state is

```
 $con = mysqli_connect(YOURLS_DB_HOST,YOURLS_DB_USER,YOURLS_DB_PASS);
     mysqli_select_db($con,YOURLS_DB_NAME);
    $users=mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($con,"SELECT email, pass FROM users"));
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($users)) {
    $email = $row['email'];
    $pass = $row['pass'];
    $user_pass3[] = array(
        $email => $pass,
        'hguhfg'=> 'nhgudfhg',
    );

}
$yourls_user_passwords = $user_pass3;
//print_r($user_pass4);
/*output Array ( [0] => Array ( [test@example.com] => test [hguhfg] => nhgudfhg ) [1] => Array ( [demo@example.com] => demo [hguhfg] => nhgudfhg ) ) but disired output is Array ( [test@example.com] => test [hguhfg] => nhgudfhg [demo@example.com] => demo); */
```

Comment: Sorry no understood. Can you give me sample code plz. Moreover I am newbies but hunting for coding expertisenes

Comment: Sorry. May be I can't elaborate my query. So I am telling this in a normal way.

Comment: That is I want to transfer all username and their respective password into an array variable $user_password = array (   like username1 => password1 , username2 => password2 ,)     by retrieving them from database. Hope now it is clear.

Comment: Yes. Exactly. I know this should not to do. That's why i don't tried it before. But it is now it is the requirement of the project (a readymade cms customization). And need only this. That's also a example for next project. That this is the backward of that project which is not in this project right?

Comment: Plz let me know the way. I have done something but that return a multidimensional array(). But I need a single dimensional array() containing email => password. And you know Same way for other info in other project not only email & password. Am I right?

Comment: Sure. Plz hold on. It may be unprofessional code as I am newbiee

Comment: Due to length limitation I have added it in question. Plz check sir/mam

Comment: I have done the program after your suggestion. Actually I could not find the way where can I start. And you have help me in that way and posted as a answer to help other like me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$database = "test";
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database); if (!($conn)) 
{
die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "SELECT email,pass FROM users";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

$newArray = array();

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) 
{
    /* loop for return all the fetched data one by one */
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
{
    /* store the data from mysqli array in variable use same code for for as much as type of data you want*/
$email=$row["email"]; 
$password=$row["pass"];
    /* you can also add some value manually into the same array like this */
$newArray['admin']= 'adminpass';
$newArray['test']= 'testpass';
    /* You have to build one array variable which includes 2 type of data 1st one as array index and 2nd one as value */
$newArray[$email]= $password;
}
} 
else 
{
echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
    /* print the array or store in another variable to use elsewhere. */
print_r($newArray);
/* or print indiviual data one by one like data1, data2 */
echo "<br>";
foreach($newArray as $x => $x_value)
{
echo "Email=" . $x . ", Password=" . $x_value;
echo "<br>";
}

/* this example shows email and password in plain text just for the special requirement of the project. It's recomended to not to use passwords in plain text and inside the code. */

    //Credits gose to https://www.facebook.com/ansarali.molla.9
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want login and password :

```
$users = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT login, password FROM sughi_users"));

$user = array();

foreach ($users as $aUser) {
    $user[$aUser['login']] = $aUser['password'];
}
```

Comment: After all of your suggestion I have done something and got this Array ( [0] => Array ( [test@example.com] => test ) [1] => Array ( [demo@example.com] => demo ) )

Comment: Now tell me how can I get Array ([test@example.com] => test [demo@example.com] => demo )

Answer (score 0):

After all of your suggestion i have done the program. Thank you everyone. Here us the perfect code.

```
$users = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT email, pass FROM users");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($users)) {
    $email = $row['email'];
    $pass = $row['pass'];
    $user_pass3[] = array(
        $email => $pass,
    );

}
foreach($user_pass3 as $arr) {
            foreach($arr as $key => $data) {
                    $user_pass[$key]  =   $data;
                }
        }

   // print_r($user_pass);
$user_pass_final = $user_pass;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `[]` notation on a variable makes it a dynamic array. So don't use `array()` after that. You can also pass a unique key inside the brackets if you prefer.

```
$users = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT email, pass FROM users");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($users)) {
    $email = $row['email'];
    $pass = $row['pass'];
    $user_pass_final[$email] = $pass;
}
print_r($user_pass_final);
```

Additionally you are double fetching, and fetching on an array which should fail so instead of:

```
$users=mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($con,"SELECT email, pass FROM users"));
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($users)) {
```

You should assign the `query` return to `$users`:

```
$users=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT email, pass FROM users");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($users)) {
```

Final note, passwords should NOT be stored in plain text. See https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/120540/why-shouldnt-i-store-passwords-in-plaintext